# 404 error loading scripts on IIS

Tags: iis

I'm running IIS 10 on Windows 10 and have installed PHP. I'm testing an app and have placed all the necessary files in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ortho. If I run a simple PHP script in that folder (http://localhost/ortho/test.php) it works. However, when I run an HTML file that references a bunch of external scripts, I'm getting a 404 for every single script. I've triple-checked that all the scripts are there (in folders under the "ortho" app folder). If I go to View Page Source and click on any of the scripts I get an error like this:

```
  This localhost page can’t be found
  No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost/ortho/jqwidgets17/jqxdata.js 
  HTTP ERROR 404
```

The scripts are located in various folders directly underneath the "ortho" app folder and are referenced like this:

```
  <SCRIPT SRC='jqwidgets17/jqxdata.js'></SCRIPT>
```

Strangely, if I just type "http://localhost" in the address bar, which normally displays the IIS splash screen, I also get a 404:

```
  No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost/
  HTTP ERROR 404
```

I don't know how it can run the PHP script in localhost when it can't find localhost!

Anyway, I've seen various posts related to similar problems that mention some things about bindings in IIS but I haven't found anything that fixes it.

Here's the site bindings window from IIS:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVI1U.jpg

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a folder target issue on the IIS configuration. If I understand correctly, your IIS binds on **c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ortho** folder (for the root directory).

If you try to access on : http://localhost/ortho/*something*, it won't work as http://localhost/ is already in this folder. It should work with this URL :

> http://localhost/jqwidgets17/jqxdata.js

Comment: No, that's not correct. The IIS root folder is c:\inetpub\wwwroot. The "ortho" folder is a subfolder where my app is located. And as I stated, the test.php script in that folder works.

Comment: Are you sure of your path : SRC='jqwidgets17/jqxdata.js' ? Where is located the HTML file that contains that script tag ?
Do you have HTML file in the root folder : c:\inetpub\wwwroot ?

Comment: Yes, that's not the problem. I'm getting the 404 even on scripts that are in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: The problem could be related to the HTML file extention, on your root directory, you can try : Open Windows Explorer, click "View" in the top bar and then check "File name extensions". The File Explorer could show that it's "index.html" but it's in fact "index.html.txt"

Comment: No, it's nothing like that.

Comment: Did you check on the `MIME Types` section of your IIS site ? - [Reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap)

Comment: After searching through a lot more posts I found the very obscure answer. It was the IIS configuration. I had to go into "Programs and Features" and under IIS go into "World Wide Web Services/Common HTTP Features and enable something called "Static Content". I've never even heard of this and still dont' really understand what it means, but it solved the problem!

Comment: Ok great, thank you for sharing your findings.